# Cross Server and Instance Login SSIS SID or ID Issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, authentication

I have some challenging login/SID/ID issues with authentication between databases on separate instances and servers.  We have a Development, Test, Pre-Production and Production server/instance environments.  They do not have the same logins in each environment.  There are developers etc. in Development, tester logins in Test, and Production does not have many of those logins.  We created a separate GIS instance in order to synchronize logins for our GIS section, because it used specific schemas where the logins had to match.  I have scripts to re-synch the database users to the appropriate login, but I have not found a way to re-synch the schemas within a database to the present, but different logins on the migrated server.

Also, we were running SSIS packages that used a specific GIS user to communicate with other databases within the instance, but when we split GIS database out to a separate instance with synched logins, the user cannot communicate with the databases that it used to in the previous instance.

I know we could use contained databases, but we're still running SQL Server 2008 R2 and it's not an option right now.

I need to know:
1) Is there a way update schema references like users in a database.  Can I script all schema ownership to dbo, then blast them away and recreate the ownership to make them match again?  Or, do you need to delete the schema (and all object associated) to match the schema/logins like I think you do?

2) How does SSIS use a login to communicate with a different server/instance in another database where the local login has priviledges?  Does it use the local login or the SID/ID of the incomming login from the SSIS running on it's server/instance?

3) Have any of you folks run into this and how did you deal with it?

Our servers contain a number of different databases that run 24/7 and I can't just take the server down for a day to try to re-synch all logins and rescript all users back into respective databases.  And logins MUST be different on the development and test servers.

Thanks a bunch in advance for any suggestions.

Robb

Comment: Can't you just re-configure the connection manager once the project has been deployed to each server?

Comment: Connection manager has been re-configured.  The issue is that the LOGIN that the SSIS is using on the instance does not authenticate to the other instance database because the login on that instance has different SID/ID.  That is what I am trying to rectify.

Comment: But thanks anyway!  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use AD users? SID mismatch is a problem with sql users.

Comment: Actually there was a problem with one of the SSIS in that it had the wrong password.  It does work.  However, the other issue involving changing the schema login is a big problem...